# Найти максимальное значение массива

Tags: c++

По условию задачи можно задать любой массив, так что я его рандомизировал. Сейчас только начал составлять код, при компиляции выдает кучу ошибок, но это не важно сейчас.

Можно ли составить код по такой логике?

```
    #include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   int mass[20];
    int max;
    int i;
    const int n=20;  
    double result = 1.0;
    int massiv[n],Xmax,Nmax,u,x;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
     massiv[i] =u=(std::rand() % 2000)-1000;
     std::cout << "{";
        std::cout << massiv[i] << " ";
        std::cout <<"} ";
}

 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        mass[i] = i;
    }

  max = mass[0];

 for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
        if(mass[i] > max){
            max = mass[i];
        }
    }
 std::cout <<"max value: "<< massiv[Nmax]<< " at index " <<Nmax;  



{
std::cin.ignore();
return 0;
}

getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Охохонюшки, придётся [полный рабочий код](https://ideone.com/BzkRSa) приводить.

Массив заполняется, выводится - заметьте, что скобки  нужны до и после цикла, но не внутри.

Затем приводится первый вариант - он только находит сам максимальный элемент, но не его позицию.

Второй вариант находит и максимум, и его индекс в массиве

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int n=20;  
    int massiv[n], Xmax, Nmax, u;
    std::cout << "{";
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
     massiv[i] =u=(std::rand() % 2000)-1000;
        std::cout << massiv[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout <<"}\n ";

    //----------------------------
    Xmax=massiv[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n;i++)
       Xmax = massiv[i]> Xmax?massiv[i]: Xmax;

    std::cout <<"Просто max: "<< Xmax << "\n" ;      

    //----------------------------
    Xmax=massiv[0];
    Nmax = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<n;i++)
       if (massiv[i] > Xmax) //или (massiv[i] > massiv[Nmax])
          {
            Xmax = massiv[i];
            Nmax = i;
          }

    std::cout <<"max value: "<< massiv[Nmax]<< " at index " << Nmax;     

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что выводится:

```
{383 -114 -223 -85 793 -665 386 -508 -351 421 -638 -973 -310
 -941 763 926 -460 426 172 736 }
 Просто max: 926
max value: 926 at index 15
```

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогло. А можете разьяснить что значит  Xmax = massiv[i]> Xmax?massiv[i]: Xmax; именно '?'. Или где можно почитать об этом,не смог найти информацию. А,все. Это тернарная операция. А зачем она здесь? Почему нельзя просто Xmax вставить?

Comment: Это тернарный оператор https://purecodecpp.com/archives/554

Answer (score 2):

для нахождения максимального int значения,создаем массив

```
    int mass[10];
    int max;
```

заполняем массив

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        mass[i] = i;
    }
```

указываем что max будет равен первому элементу

```
    max = mass[0];
```

ищем максимальное значение в массиве

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(mass[i] > max){
            max = mass[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: В таком случае второй цикл имеет смысл начать с `i=1`.

Comment: Сделал как у Вас,но ответ выдает абсурдный max value: 19 at index -1

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил два раза уменьшить цикл :

```
int max_from_array(const int* m, const int size)
{
    int p = (size % 2) ? size / 2 + 1 : size / 2,
            max = *m;
    for (int i = 1 ; p < size; ++p, ++i)
    {
        if (m[p] > max)
            max = (m[p] > m[i]) ? m[p] : m[i];
        else if (max < m[i])
            max = m[i];             
    }
    return max;
}
int main()
{  
    const int n = 20;
    int massiv[n] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        massiv[i] = rand()%2000 - 1000; // функция не в пространстве std
        std::cout << massiv[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << max_from_array(massiv, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выглядит у Вас лучше,но к сожалению,я не понимаю как работает предложенный Вами код,так что смысла использовать его не вижу. Возможно как разберусь...

Answer (score 0):

ну если совсем писать лень, то можно и так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int mass[]{3,12,4,1,0};
    int maxim=*max_element(begin(mass), end(mass));
    cout<<maxim<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```